# Query single column, all rows in Postgres 2D Array

Tags: postgresql, array

Is there any way to fix the query below so I don't have to specify an arbitrary max row count?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS array_test;

CREATE TABLE array_test (
  id serial primary key,
  name text,
  array_column integer[][]
);

insert into array_test (name, array_column) VALUES
  ('rowa', ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),
  ('rowb', ARRAY[[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]);
```

This does what I want, but I don't like hard-coding 9999 as an arbitrary max row count:

```
select array_column[1:9999][2:2] from array_test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions [`array_upper()` and `array_lower()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to identify array dimensions dynamically:

```
select array_column[1:array_upper(array_column, 1)][2:2] from array_test;
```

While being at it, if arrays can have non-standard dimenstions, it would be safer to use

```
SELECT array_column[array_lower(array_column, 1):array_upper(array_column, 1)][2:2]
FROM   array_test;
```

**One subtle difference**: While your code returns an *empty array* for an empty array in the base table, my alternatives returns *NULL* since `array_lower()` and `array_upper()` return NULL. (For NULL in the base table, all return NULL.

I suggest to use a **more revealing test case**, so you don't miss corner cases:

```
INSERT INTO array_test (name, array_column) VALUES
  ('rowa', ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
, ('rowb', ARRAY[[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
, ('rowc', ARRAY[[1,2,3]])
, ('rowd', ARRAY[[1],[2],[3]])
, ('rowe', '{}')
, ('rowf', NULL);
```

There is another "hack" to do *exactly* the same as your original, but never cut off elements. Use the **maximum possible array bounds** (which are `integer` numbers):

```
SELECT array_column[-2147483648:2147483647][2:2] FROM array_test;
```

Inspired by Daniel's answer on my related question:

- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12012285/939860)